# Blackberry - how to figure out the free space on a device from code

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I need to know if there is enough space on the Blackberry device before saving a file.
Is there a way to know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The availableSize() method in the [FileConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#availableSize%28%29) class should give you what you need.